# React Nextjs bad performance with almost empty app

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, vercel, lighthouse

I have created a new Nextjs project and deployed to Vercel.

The project is still almost empty, only one div with few texts on it,
But the performance in lighthouse: Time to interactive - TTL and Total blocking time - TBT are already marked as an issue.

What can cause it?

[image]

Comment: It is generally better to test in incognito mode with extensions disabled. You can also use the official tools https://web.dev/measure/ and https://pagespeed.web.dev/ to test. They all give a near perfect score for you site. The only opportunity being shown is "Reduce initial server response time", which is because of the free nature of vercel hosting. Use a dedicated hosting to overcome it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is quite strange, Lighthouse shows a near-to-perfect score of your website on my computer.

Are you:

- Using some browser plugins that may affect performance?
- Having a slower internet connection at times?

I remember having adblockers generating some console errors and warnings on my website for my Google Analytics Tag, that lowered the score until I disabled that plugin on my particular website.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You're correct. All major libraries like Angular, React, Vue, Next, etc perform badly when running lighthouse against their default slow 4g throttling.

Even when you use SSR solutions; the initial script loaded is probably somewhere around 150kb-200kb for a regular page; thats a lot of processing causing a "long task"; which results in the high total blocking time.

However these libraries perform fine for modern devices.

Thats the thing; if you need to score well in lighthouse metrics for SEO reasons or because of your audience; then use a jamstack solution like Sveltekit or something.